# Issue in django proejct with two version of python installed on centos server

Tags: python, django

Working on django1.9 project, the issue is that default python installed on my server is 2.6 and i have to use python 2.7 for django 1.9. I have installed python2.6 on server.
And while creating django projected i hve created it using virtual environment with python2.7 but whenever i am trying to access project it gives me 500 internal server error.
When i checked my apache http error log file if found that it is still using python2.6 for my project.

```
Error :- [Sat Aug 06 07:48:13 2016] [error] [client 112.196.41.202]      fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
[Sat Aug 06 07:48:13 2016] [error] [client 112.196.41.202]                      ^
[Sat Aug 06 07:48:13 2016] [error] [client 112.196.41.202]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

mod_wsgi configuration is :-

```
WSGIScriptAlias /onpointtickets /home/onpoin21/public_html/onpointtickets/onpointtickets/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/onpoin21/public_html/onpointtickets

<Directory /home/onpoin21/public_html/onpointtickets/onpointtickets>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Post your configurations

Comment: LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so

    WSGIScriptAlias /onpointtickets /home/onpoin21/public_html/onpointtickets/onpointtickets/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /home/onpoin21/public_html/onpointtickets

    <Directory /home/onpoin21/public_html/onpointtickets/onpointtickets>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

Comment: Please post the entire virtualhost block as *part of the question* not a comment

Comment: I've not used mod_wsgi, but I would imagine that there is a way to specify which python you want to use... Does it automatically pickup the fact you have a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.6. You cannot make it use a virtual environment for Python 2.7 and wouldn't be able to use it with application code which requires Python 2.7. You need to reinstall mod_wsgi with it recompiled for Python 2.7.